# Firebug debugger ignore setTimeout? How to test it?

Tags: javascript, html, firebug

```
Windows 7
Firefox 10.0.1
```

I have simple setTimeout logic that I want to test using Firebug debugger with few breakpoints.

**test.js**

```
console.log("one");   
setTimeout(function(){ console.log("hmm"); }, 5000);
console.log("two");   //breakpoint here
console.log("three");
```

**test.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/test.js" ></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Using `Firebug debugger`, I put breakpoint in the commented line (where console.log("two") )
and when I load the html page I get output:

```
one
```

and process halt at the breakpoint as expected but **setTimeout never gets executed.**

Is this firebug debugger bug? Has anyone seen this before?

**UPDATE:**

I investigate bit more and found:

If you click on "continue" during debugger mode and go through breakpoints within 5000ms (which is specified time in setTimeout), the "hmm" msg shows up.

If you halt at breakpoint for more than 5000ms then "hmm" msg won't show up even after "continue" button.

Comment: What happening if you place the SCRIPT element at the bottom of BODY?

Comment: This is perfectly valid timeout behaviour. If you break at any point in the debugger, nothing will be executed until you continue - timeouts included

Comment: @madr: nothing different. After "continue" with breakpoints, output is "one two three" and that's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setTimeout` triggers only after Javascript execution thread becomes free, even if the time is out while thread is busy. Putting a break point just suspends the thread and it stays busy while stoppend on it. So, this code will return

```
one
two 
three
hmmm //(in 5 seconds, if no breakpoint, at once if you stop at a breakpoint for more than 5 seconds and then run the code further)
```

This is the correct `setTimeout` behaviour.

Comment: If I stopped at breakpoints for more than 5000ms, "hmm" from setTimeout never get outputted.

Comment: It will work only after the initializing script execution is complete. And you are suspending it's execution with a breakpoint.

Answer (score 2):

## This is a Firebug bug ;)

Please look into [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=1830).

Comment: I ran into the same issue trying to debug and having my setTimeout calls disappear on me. Looks like there is a patch out: https://github.com/firebug/firebug/commit/70a32d81406a49853330310baed6305e027233e2

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a problem with it. The code inside setTimeout executes 5 seconds later, so your expected output is

one

two

three

hmmm

Comment: hmm.. my console only get one two three and no output from setTimeout...weird

Answer (score 0):

You can just set breakpoint inside the callback to the setTimeout
And continue with step-in inside of it